# Multilinear maps: is $\phi(av_1,v_2)$ always equal to $\phi(v_1,av_2)$?

Tags: multilinear-algebra

I am learning about multilinear maps by myself and the book I'm following gives a definition which is somewhat vague.

That's the definition: Given vector spaces $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_p,W$. A mapping $\phi:V_1\times\dots\times V_p \rightarrow W$ is multilinear if it is linear in each argument.

Let us consider the case in which $p=2$. Let $a \in \mathbb{K}$, $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$. Are the following steps correct?

$$
\phi(av_1,v_2) = a\phi(v_1,v_2)=\phi(v_1,av_2)
$$

Comment: It's quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are correct. The first equality holds by the linearity in the first argument, and the second equality holds by the linearity in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct and make sure never to confuse 'linear' with 'multilinear'.  Multilinear means linear in each of the $p$ variables.  $\Lambda^p V$ is the vector space of real-valued $p$-linear alternating forms, meaning that they have to be linear for each of the $p$ variables in exactly the way you just described, as well as being alternating.

I will provide an example which you will be seeing soon anyway in the book if you have not seen it.  The wedge (or exterior) product of a $p$-form and a $q$-form is bilinear.

$(\phi_1 + \phi_2) \wedge \psi=\phi_1 \wedge \psi + \phi_2 + \psi,$

$\phi \wedge (a\psi)=a(\phi \wedge \psi).$